# How to dynamically update a Customer Match audience without manual file uploads?

Tags: google-apis-explorer

Is it possible to dynamically update a Customer Match audience?

if there is a way to add automatically new emails to this audience. I don't want to have to upload a new file every day. Without using any third party tool!